# This procedure (elementSeparator) is giving a type error in ReasonML

Tags: types, typeerror, reason

This code:

```
let initialRows = 5;
    let initialCols = 7;

    /* 
    Player 1 is P1, Player 2 is P2
    */

    type whichPlayer =
      | P1
      | P2;

    /* 
    Either Player 1 or Player 2 has won the game,
    it is a draw, or it is ongoing where either
    it is Player 1's turn or Player 2's turn
    */

    type status =
      | Win(whichPlayer)
      | Draw
      | Ongoing(whichPlayer);

    /*
    The current state of the game is represented by a list of lists of tuples: 
    containing the column number of the occupancy as the first element,
    and the occupant of the specified slot as the second element,
    and a status specification indicating which player's turn it is, or
    whether the game has ended in a win or a draw.
    */

    type state = 
      | State(list(list((int, whichPlayer))), status);

    /*
    A move is represented by an int, corresponding to
    the column number of the desired occupancy 
    */

    type move = 
      | Move(int);

let rec createEmptySpaces: int => string = num =>
    switch(num){
      | x when x > 1 => "( )" ++ createEmptySpaces(num-1)
      | 1 => "( )"
    };      

let rec elementSeparator: (list((int, whichPlayer)), int) => string = (lst, num) =>
switch(lst){
  | [(colNum, p), (colNum2, p2), ... tl] when num == 1 =>{
    let difference = colNum2 - colNum;
    if(colNum != 1){
      createEmptySpaces(colNum-1) ++
      if(p == P1){
        "(o)" ++ if(difference != 1){
                    createEmptySpaces(difference - 1)
                 }
      } else {
        "(x)" ++ if(difference != 1){
                    createEmptySpaces(difference - 1)
                 }
      } 
      ++ elementSeparator([(colNum2, p2)]@tl, num + 1)
    } else {
      if(p == P1){
        "(o)" ++ if(difference != 1){
                    createEmptySpaces(difference - 1)
                 }
      } else {
        "(x)" ++ if(difference != 1){
                    createEmptySpaces(difference - 1)
                 }
      }
      ++ elementSeparator([(colNum2, p2)]@tl, num + 1)
    }
  }

  | [] => ""
};

elementSeparator([(1, P1), (3, P2), (7, P1)], 1);
elementSeparator([(3, P2), (5, P2)], 1);
elementSeparator([(2, P1), (3, P2), (4, P1), (6, P2)], 1);
```

is giving me the error:

```
Error: This expression has type string but an expression was expected of type unit
```

for the third if expression. I am trying to create a row of 
"(x)"'s, "(o)"'s, and "( )"'s. I do not know why it would be throwing this error as elementSeparator is supposed to output a string. Every time I try to concatenate another string (via function, procedure, expression, etc.) after the second if expression, it throws this error. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 2):

`if` expressions without an `else` branch always need to return a value of type `unit` (because that is the type of the expression if the `if` condition does not resolve to `true`).

One can solve it by adding an `else` branch that returns the empty string `""`, or just using the ternary operator for brevity:

```
difference != 1 ? createEmptySpaces(difference - 1) : ""
```